# JPA: query to get results based on value of foreign key defined in the entity class?

Tags: java, jpa, entity

Netbean 6.9 generated the following JPA entity class from this SQL Server 2008 table:
[image]

I want to get all the ProductDescriptors that have a specific SKU value.  Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ProductDescriptors WHERE SKU='something'
```

Given the entity class, what's the Java code to get the results?

### Thanks.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ProductDescriptors")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductDescriptors.findAll",     query = "SELECT p FROM ProductDescriptors p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductDescriptors.findByDescriptorID", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductDescriptors p WHERE p.descriptorID = :descriptorID"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductDescriptors.findByLanguageCode", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductDescriptors p WHERE p.languageCode = :languageCode"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductDescriptors.findByTitle", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductDescriptors p WHERE p.title = :title"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductDescriptors.findByIsDefault", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductDescriptors p WHERE p.isDefault = :isDefault"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductDescriptors.findByBody", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductDescriptors p WHERE p.body = :body")})
public class ProductDescriptors implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "DescriptorID")
    private Integer descriptorID;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "LanguageCode")
    private String languageCode;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Title")
    private String title;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "IsDefault")
    private boolean isDefault;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Body")
    private String body;
    @JoinColumn(name = "SKU", referencedColumnName = "SKU")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Products products;
```

...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this:

```
@PersistenceContext( unitName = "youPersistenceUnitHere" )
private EntityManager _entityManager;

public List<ProductDescriptors> getProductDescriptorsBySku( String sku ) {
   Query query = _entityManager.createQuery( "Select ProductDescriptors from ProductDescriptors pd where pd.products.sku = ?1" );
   query.setParameter( 1, sku );
   return new ArrayList<ProductDescriptors>( query.getResultList() );
}
```

Comment: Another somewhat similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180905/jpa-join-table-syntax

Comment: Ok, I added a solution there. As I commented there, I don't know that you need to involve the products table\entity set; so I left that out. If you do, comment and I'll look again.