# JPA: join table syntax

Tags: java, jpa

Given the following entity (some columns omitted from this long definition for brevity):

```
@Table(name = "Products")
public class Products implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "SKU")
    private String sku;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ProductName")
    private String productName;

    private boolean allowPreOrder;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productsCollection")
    private Collection<Categories> categoriesCollection;
    @JoinTable(name = "Products_CrossSell", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "SKU", referencedColumnName = "SKU")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "CrossSKU", referencedColumnName = "SKU")})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Products> productsCollection;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productsCollection")
    private Collection<Products> productsCollection1;
    @JoinTable(name = "Products_Related", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "SKU", referencedColumnName = "SKU")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "RelatedSKU", referencedColumnName = "SKU")})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Products> productsCollection2;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productsCollection2")
    private Collection<Products> productsCollection3;
```

How do I get the set of related products for a given product SKU?

The products_related table looks like this:

[image]

I know how to get the answer using SQL but I'm new to JPA so I haven't quite grokked the API and query syntax yet.

Comment: +1 for stumping me - I'd like to see the solution. I deleted my previous answer as it was wrong. If I figure it out I'll post a new one or undelete it. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me there are some unnecessary collections defined. Anyway:

```
@JoinTable(name = "Products_Related", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "SKU", referencedColumnName = "SKU")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "RelatedSKU", referencedColumnName = "SKU")})
@ManyToMany
private Collection<Products> productsCollection2;
```

This piece (it is present in your code) should give you the desired products. Just rename it to `relatedProducts`, and the respective setter/getter.

**Update:** You can get the object by:

```
Product p = entityManager.find(Product.class, yourProductId);
p.getRelatedProducts();
```

Obtaining the entity manager depends on your setup, and a better place to look for how to obtain it, is a tutorial.

Comment: Please let me know what the call would look like for a given sku value?  How would I call getRelatedProducts() (after I renamed it from getProductsCollection2()) and on what object?

Comment: Thank you!  You made it look easy.  :-)

Comment: @Bozho, how would you go about finding something in a collection without using the find by ID?

Comment: @javamonkey79 if you don't have an entity (identified by id), you don't have a collection. So how do you get it? If you have anything particular in mind, ask a separate question, providing relevant details.

Comment: @Bozho I was working on this last night and I didn't notice the obvious solution that you posted. I was trying to find the entity from p.productsCollection2.sku. I can open a new question, but it seems strange to do so only referencing someone else's.

Comment: @Bozho: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187509/jpa-getting-entity-from-value-in-collection